# Are all bluetooth keyboards slow to respond?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra, bluetooth

I've been given a MacBook Pro (now running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6), and a third-party bluetooth keyboard. I have a number of issues with the keyboard:

- it's not very sensitive - many keystrokes get missed
- if I leave the computer for a few minutes I have to wait about 10 seconds before I can use the keyboard again
- it disconnects while I'm typing
- the function keys are not affected by the keyboard setting in System Settings (I always have to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+ a function key, although the built-in keyboard is affected

I have a couple of wireless keyboards for my Windows PCs, and they don't have any of the above problems. I spoke to an Apple retailer, and they told me I would have all the same issues with a genuine Apple Magic Keyboard. I find it incredible that Apple would sell such an inferior product. I don't want to spend AU$179 just to find out I still have all the same problems.

Was what I was told by the Apple retailer accurate that a genuine Apple Magic Keyboard would have all the same issues?

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question, but it may be worth asking another question specifically about your issue and how you might troubleshoot that. Be sure you outline what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

**No! What you have been told is simply not true!**

I have been using Apple Wireless keyboards for 8 or 9 years and have not experienced these problems. Neither have I experienced similar problems with a Magic Mouse or Magic Trackpad.

That said, without further troubleshooting it's impossible to say *why* you're having these problems. It could well be that the issue has nothing to do with your keyboard and something else is at play here, but the simplest way to rule that out is to try another wireless keyboard and see what happens.

Comment: See my linked question. $179 is a lot to pay for an experiment.

Comment: Agreed! I wouldn't spend $179 for an experiment either unless I knew I could return it. However, since you're talking about a MBP it'd be easy enough to bring that in with you to test it first. I also thought you could *potentially* test it with one of the other wireless keyboards you've got, but of course I'm assuming they're Bluetooth keyboards. Anyway, I think we've answered *this* question, so I'll take a look at your other question later today.

Comment: The other two are USB 2.0, and the MacBook has USB 3.0, so I can't test them as I don't have an adapter, and there's no guarantee a working USB keyboard means a second Bluetooth keyboard would work anyway.