# Get bluetooth keyboard working identically to built-in keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra, bluetooth

This is a follow-up question to [Are all bluetooth keyboards slow to respond?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/334475/108934).

I've been given a MacBook Pro (now running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6), and a third-party bluetooth keyboard (J.Burrows). I have a number of issues with the keyboard:

- it's not very sensitive - many keystrokes get missed
- if I leave the computer for a few minutes I have to wait about 10 seconds before I can use the keyboard again
- it disconnects while I'm typing
- the function keys are not affected by the keyboard setting in System Settings (I always have to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+ a function key, although the built-in keyboard is affected

I've tried switching the keyboard off and back on again, and I've looked through System Settings, but "Set Up Bluetooth Keyboard..." has no options, even when the keyboard entry under "Devices" is double-clicked. It only has an X to remove the keyboard.

What can I do to resolve these problems? I don't have another bluetooth keyboard I can swap it with.

Apparently this is how these keyboards work. See the [reviews on Officeworks](https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/p/j-burrows-wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-jbbkb708#!reviews).

Comment: Who makes this 3rd party keyboard?  You don't have another keyboard, but can you pair it to a *different* computer?  Can you pair it to your phone/tablet?

Comment: @Allan I probably can pair it to my iPad, but my iPad doesn't have a built-in keyboard, so how do I know if it's behaving properly? E.g. the function keys?

Comment: You're testing lag and connection stability, not function keys.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination and often requires patience.

As a starting point, I'd try to reset both the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller.

**IMPORTANT:** This will reset **all** connected Bluetooth devices, including any wireless keyboard or mouse, so they will need to be reconnected.

Before commencing, you will need to have the Bluetooth icon showing in the menu bar. If it is not there, open System Preferences > Bluetooth and enable the option *Show Bluetooth in Menu Bar*.

**Resetting the macOS Bluetooth Device List and Bluetooth Controller**

Follow these steps:

1. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys and at the same time and click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Once the menu is showing, release the keys.
2. From the Bluetooth menu, choose Debug > Remove All Devices
3. Hold down both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys again and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar.
4. From the Bluetooth menu,  choose Debug > Reset the Bluetooth Module
5. Restart your Mac
6. Setup your keyboard again

After doing the above, test your keyboard for a while to determine if it's now working better.

If it's not, there are other things we can try/test for on the MBP side of things. However, before doing that, the next step should be confirming the keyboard itself is okay. If possible, test the keyboard with another computer and confirm it's working okay with that. If it isn't, then replace your keyboard batteries of make sure they're fully charged and test again.

Let me know how you go up to this point and if necessary we'll proceed further.

Comment: No, after following your 6 steps, the keyboard immediately disconnected itself. I had already replaced the batteries since I forgot Bluetooth?/Mac? keyboards only last a month on batteries. My PC USB keyboards work for many months without changing the batteries. I'm still having problems with the occasional missed keystroke. I still have to press fn+esc to get esc to work regardless of the function setting.

Comment: Just trying to clarify your comment - Has there been any sort of improvement since following these steps, or are you still experiencing all of the same issues? And have you been able to test the keyboard with another computer? BTW, what brand/model is the keyboard?

Comment: I edited the question. Still the same. I'm just going down to the shop with the MacBook to see if I can test a keyboard there.

Comment: That's great - whatever happens will be valuable from a troubleshooting point of view! :)

Comment: I just bought a Magic Keyboard. It works (almost) as I expect a keyboard to work.